# Weird shading when applying textures & materials

Tags: texturing, unity

My avatar shows up fine in blender, but when imported into unity and the materials and textures are applied, it shows up weird and I have no idea what it is. I don't think it's a unity problem though, I think I messed up something in blender.
[image]

[image]

Comment: A picture of your material setup would help. Long story short: to get the closes result, make sure you use only a principled shader with either raw values or image textures with UV maps. Anything else is most likely not supported by Unity, the exporter, or both.

Comment: I figured it out, it was a problem with normals, everything looks fine now it's just the antennae looks broken